# Generating IoT analytics using firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have around 25 devices located in different parts of my city. Each device generates temperature and humidity data as a write in the Firestore database. Every hour I want to average the temp and humidity info and store/append it as a map in a single document.

```
{ DateTime: { temp: x, humidity: y }}
{ DateTime: { temp: x1, humidity: y1 }}
```

I'm using python to get the data and average it and then write it in the document.

Then I want to load this data in the front end to show the user analytics based on hours, days, weeks, and months. But Firestore cannot store more than 5 MB in a single document so I will run out of space fast. Is there any better way of generating analytics from stored data in collections?

Most of the people I talk to recommend switching away from firebase for such use cases, but I do believe there is a way of doing this that is generally a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Firestore cannot store more than 5 MB in a single document

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), it's actually 1 Mib the maximum size. But that is more than enough to store such data as yours.

Since you cannot store all the data of all devices in a single document, I recommend you store only the data that corresponds to a single day. If you're only storing numbers, maybe it can fit in one document the data for a week, or even for a month. So you have to measure that.

So in this way, there are no limitations. You can create as many documents as you need. And of course, you won't get "out of space".

Comment: Hey RealRK. Can I help you with other information?